# Why does $\;\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{n}{n!^{1/n}}=e$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have tried to show that this limit :
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty }\frac{n}{n!^{\frac 1 n}}=e$$

using  $ \lim  (1+\frac 1 n)^{\frac 1 n} , n \to \infty $ , I don't find any equivalence , however wolfram alpha says that is $e$ as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+(n+%2F+((n!)%5E(1%2Fn)),+n+to+infty), then how do I evaluate it ?

Comment: That's not good enough. You need at least a weak form of Stirling's formula.

Comment: As per @DeepSea's answer, this trick is useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118515/if-f-is-riemann-integrable-on-0-1-then-lim-frac1n-sum-fk-n-int/

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: This is essentially the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2685822/how-can-we-prove-that-l-lim-n-to-infty-frac-log-left-fracnnn-rig

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As an alternative without Stirling, note that

$$\frac{n}{n!^{\frac 1 n}}=\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^{\frac 1 n}=(a_n)^\frac1n$$

and

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{n^n}=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\to e$$

then by [ratio-root criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335500/do-the-sequences-from-the-ratio-and-root-tests-converge-to-the-same-limit) $\frac{n}{n!^{\frac 1 n}}\to e$.

Answer (score 6):

We have: $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}  -\dfrac{1}{n}\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \ln \left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right)= -\displaystyle \int_{0}^1\ln xdx=1\implies \displaystyle \lim_{ n\to \infty} \ln\left(\dfrac{n}{n!^{1/n}}\right)=1\implies \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n}{n!^{1/n}}=e$.

Comment: +1, I quit, typing essentially the same answer :)

Comment: (+1) I've used this same approach before.  Well done.

Answer (score 2):

By [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

$$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$

then

$$\frac{n}{n!^{\frac 1 n}}\sim \frac{n}{(\sqrt{2 \pi n})^\frac1n\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)}\to e$$

Comment: Good answer. However I feel this is a bit circular, since Stirling's approximation uses similar limits, although it's probably ok. Does anyone know a different approach?

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik I've just added an answer by root-ratio criteria

Comment: I just saw your other answer, thx!